# How do I BULK INSERT shared text files from MS OneDrive for Business into SQL-Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, onedrive

We are writing a bunch of data (text files, images, MS Excel spreadsheets) to a laptop and we want to share the data among several different team members.

The University has MS OneDrive for Business for free so we are using that as our file sharing system (our personal DropBoxes are all full!). We've successfully uploaded the data to OneDrive and I can see it in my browser (that was pretty easy).

So I have two problems:

1. Quite honestly I was surprised (and horrified) that I would have to download the files individually when they were shared with me! I want to have an automated task that is looking for new files in OneDrive.
2. SQL Server allows for `BULK INSERT` for shared data files (via the universal naming convention like *\Servername\Sharename\Path\Filename*) and since DropBox just grabs a whole folder and syncs it to a physical location on my disk it would work fine because I can write a `BULK INSERT` statement that grabs any file on the disk. I don't think that is how OneDrive for Business works.

So my question is what steps do I need to follow to:

1. Check this OneDrive For Business folder regularly (once/day)
2. `BULK INSERT` the new text/image files into my SQL Server database

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive actually does have a sync client that keeps your OneDrive in sync with a folder on your PC. You can download it here. https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/download/

Comment: I need it for OneDrive For Business of which there is a client (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2903984) but I cannot get it to sync.

Comment: Try downloading the client at the link I gave you; it's the newest client, which works for both OneDrive Personal and Business. The support article you linked to is for the old business-only client that's being replaced with the new one.